# nginx - reverse proxy for Apache and Socket.io on a SSL enabled site

Tags: nginx, php, node.js

My `SSL` secured web application consists of Apache server (PHP) and NodeJS (Socket.io). To overcome the issue of blocked ports on various networks, I decided to use `nginx` for redirecting the requests to the respective ports I set. But I have been struggling to configure everything in a right manner.

**Edited:**

I want to use nginx to listen all the requests on `port 443` and point it to my PHP/NodeJS service. Here's the configuration for `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file:

```
server {

    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate    /var/www/project/mynode/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/www/project/mynode/private.key;

    server_name domain.com ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    root /var/www/;

    location /project/{
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:442/project/;
    }

    location /backend/{
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080/project/angular/backend/;
    }

    location /connect/{
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to connect to the socket in following manner:

```
io.connect("https://www.domain.com/connect");
```

but socket never gets connected. Apache's services work fine.

This is the error I face:

```
https://www.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1434534878619-0 404 (Not Found)
```

However, when I mention the port, it works fine. Here's the working code for it:

```
io.connect("https://www.domain.com:9000");
```

I configured the `ports.conf` and `apache2/sites-available/default` files as per the documentations and guides, tried all that I could interpret, but I still am failing to get my socket connected.

Comment: Can't `nginx` be configured to listen over 443? Also,  I don't really understand why you need to stack both `nginx` and `apache`.

Comment: Yes, tried to listen over 443 but I got **Bad Gateway** error. And yes, I did have that thought, but I wasn't entirely sure about everything, so decided to run `apache` on a different port.

Comment: @dawud, I have edited my question after advancing a bit, would you please read it again? And I would prefer to not switch to nginx from apache completely, cause it would require me confiiguring everything that I did on apache.